# Spring mongo: Query Subdocument array to get matching subdocuments using IN clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi have a collection as below:

**clientPref**

```
{
  clntId: 1234,
  clntType: "internal",
  status: "PROCESSED",
  prefs: [
    {
      name: "AAA",
      value: "value1"
    },
    {
      name: "BBB",
      value: "value2"
    },
    {
      name: "CCC",
      value: "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I find by `prefs.name $in ("AAA", "CCC")`, I'm getting all the subdocuments along with the parent.
I then tried using `prefs.$: 1` in the fields parameter of @Query but then it's returning the first matching subdocument only.

**Desired output**

```
{
  clntId: 1234,
  clntType: "internal",
  status: "PROCESSED",
  prefs: [
    {
      name: "AAA",
      value: "value1"
    },
    {
      name: "CCC",
      value: "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way I can get AAA and CCC subdocument by using `@Query` annotation. If not then how to do it using aggregation? Still pretty new to mongo so not able to figure out a way to get desired result.

Comment: If you find a better way, could you please post that? If the below answer is helpful, could you upvote/approve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `project` what is needed.

```
{
 "prefs.$":1,
 "clntType":1,
 "status":1
}
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oxguuzorp31)

Query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "prefs.name": "AAA"
},
{
  "prefs.$": 1,
  "clntType": 1,
  "status": 1
})
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "clntType": "internal",
    "prefs": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "value": "value1"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PROCESSED"
  }
]
```

To get all sub doc:

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rsi7q7Bd1c_)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$prefs"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "prefs.name": {
        "$in": [
          "AAA",
          "CCC"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you want to group all the data again, you can do [play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M_Lhm13uiHE)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$prefs"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "prefs.name": {
        "$in": [
          "AAA",
          "CCC"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I need multiple subdocuments in the result matching with "name" field which I pass in the "$in" clause of find. I tried projecting as you mentioned already but it just gives me the first matching subdocument of the "name" which it finds in the document.

Comment: If I remove the unwind aggregator it still gives me all the subdocuments. The second solution also doesn't give the desired outcome that I want. I want the subdocuments array in the parent without unwinding it like this {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "clntId": 1234,
    "clntType": "internal",
    "prefs": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "value": "value1"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "value": "value3"
      }
    ]
  }

Comment: Without unwind it is not possible. You need to play with aggregation frameworks to get it. But it will result you in more pipeline stages. It's like you cannot skip p, q, r in alphabets just because you don't need. There could be another way in aggregation framework but it ll take you to the same amount or more number of pipeline stages.